# how to attach correctly a file in laravel email?

Tags: php, email, routes, attachment, laravel-5.7

I am developing an module who send email to the persons who register in the web site, i am testing the route that send emails by separed, however when I want to attach a file to the email, the app craches and says that

> it is unable to open the file for reading.

```
Route::get('sendemail', function () {    
    $data = array(
        'name' => "Curso Laravel",
    );    
    Mail::send('emails.welcome', $data, function ($message) {    
        $message->from('emaiconphp@gmail.com', 'Curso Laravel');    
        $message->to('emilianocarrillopaez@gmail.com')->subject('test email Curso Laravel');    
        $message->attach('./images/banner.jpg');    
    });    
    return "Tú email ha sido enviado correctamente";    
});
```

[image]

Comment: are you sure about images location, with a relative path it depends on script location, try a full path to be sure. Also its a lot easier to help if you post your code as text on the site, not link to an image

Answer (score 0):

Brooooooooooo, i did it. My mistake was the double the double point in $message->attach('../images/banner.jpg'); I onli change it for one point, like this $message->attach('./images/banner.jpg');